# Adding a Chevron at the left end of a Textbox with space/padding

Tags: swift, image, textbox

I have been successfully able to add a chevron to a Textbox but it is "touching" the edge of the textbox, as seen in the image below
[image]

I would like to add a white space between the chevron image and the textbox left boarder, how can I do so?!

Here is my current code:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let image = UIImage(named: "Chevron_down_120")
imageView.image = image
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
countryCodeTextField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
countryCodeTextField.rightView = imageView //leftView       
countryCodeTextField.addSubview(imageView)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First quick solution is to add extra padding to your imageView frame **width** as it's contentMode is scaleAspectFit so it will work just fine.

Comment: Or create a custom UITextField class and use that class instead of UITextField. Override - rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) to set the rect that you need with some extra padding.